# MapServer: Output angled label with Cairo/PDF

Tags: mapserver, pdf

We're trying to output a PDF with the Cairo driver.
When printing a label with ANGLE set to follow, auto or an attribute, it fails regularly.

Has anyone experienced this before? A solution or workaround?

/Kristian